# Implement PHP Markdown class in a Wordpress Theme - Class 'Markdown' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, class, markdown

I am trying to implement the [php-markdown](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown) class in a Wordpress theme.

I am wondering if I am going about this the right way. I have put the `Michelf` folder into `themeroot/_/inc/php/` and in my `header.php` I have the following:

```
<?php

    set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.get_template_directory().'/_/inc/php');

    spl_autoload_register(function($class){
        require preg_replace('{\\\\|_(?!.*\\\\)}', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ltrim($class, '\\')).'.php';
    });

    use \Michelf\Markdown;

?>
```

Then I am trying to use it like so:

`<?php echo Markdown::defaultTransform($someText); ?>`

Which results in the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Markdown' not found in
>   /directories/.../index.php
>   on line 11

It works if I do the following:

`<?php echo Michelf\Markdown::defaultTransform($someText); ?>`

Which is odd because the [readme itself](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/blob/lib/Readme.php) doesn't require the `Michelf`?

Just wondering if I am going about including this class the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo in the docs. You need the Michelf\ because it's namespaced. Look at Markdown.php, line 13, and you'll see.