# 'Michelf\Markdown' class not found

Tags: php, class, markdown

I would like to use [Michelf Markdown Parser](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$my_text = " a";

use \Michelf\Markdown;
$my_html = Markdown::defaultTransform($my_text);

echo "end";
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I got the error:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Class 'Michelf\Markdown' not found in /path/to/index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in **/path/to/index.php** on line **8**

I searched a bit, found that someone [had a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294483/implement-php-markdown-class-in-a-wordpress-theme-class-markdown-not-found). But adding 'Michelf\' didn't change anything:

```
$my_html = \Michelf\Markdown::defaultTransform($my_text);
```

I got the same error message.

This is my file tree:

```
/path/to/
  |- index.php
  `- Michelf/
      |- Markdown.php
      |- MarkdownInterface.php
      `- […]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package supposed you use an autoloader if you're using like right that way. What I meant is [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). I could be wrong but, **if you are using composer**, path of the library should be laying under `/vendor` directory

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Michelf\Markdown;

$my_text = 'a';
$my_html = Markdown::defaultTransform($my_text);
```

Or if you're not with composer, readme of the library is telling you how to use it [here](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown#usage-without-an-autoloader)

```
require_once 'Michelf/Markdown.inc.php';
use Michelf\Markdown;

$my_text = 'a';
$my_html = Markdown::defaultTransform($my_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
composer require michelf/php-markdown
composer dump-autoload
```